# Send file and line number to tmux

Tags: line-numbers, tmux

I want to send commands to tmux to run Elixir tests from vim. Using the `%` variable allows me to run the command to run a test for a single file. The relevant line in my `.vimrc` is

`nmap <silent> <leader>ef :! tmux send -t 0.1 'mix test %:p' Enter<CR><c-L>`

This sends, for example, `mix test /path/to/spec.exs` when I'm in a spec. That works for testing a single file.

Now I want to be able to run a single test. The command would have the format

`mix test /path/to/test.exs:<lineno>`, so the path, a colon, and the line number. I tried things like `line(.)`, but I can't figure out how to interpolate that inside of a `tmux send` string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of inserting line number in a shell command:

```
:exe "!echo " . line(".")
```

So your mapping would be something like this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>ef :exe "!tmux send -t 0.1 'mix test %:p:" . line(".") . "' Enter"<CR><C-L>
```

I run `tmux` so I was able to test that the command appeared in a tmux pane (though I can't actually verify the command since I don't have 'mix').

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong concatenation operator. Also, `<c-L>` clears the output of the shell exit code so vim doesn't switch to the output. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, so it does. That's handy. I'll add it back. Cheers.